# Renaming packages in the project

Tags: eclipse, refactoring, package, rename, eclipse-luna

I have a very big eclipse web project with hundreds of packages, but I have to rename all of those packages without hurting any functionality in the code.
Is there any fast and precise way to do it ?
I am using java EE -Eclipse Luna.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [refactor](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-menu-refactor.htm) > rename .

Comment: please take back-up before refract/renaming your packages to be in safe side.